# Can you extract or generate PDB files from 3rd party Precompiled LIB files

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2017

I have a set of 3rd party .LIB file that I am working with and when I compile the project I get a lot of LNK4099 errors.  Now I know I can suppress these by using an appropriate linker option, but I was wondering if it is possible to extract/generate the .PDB files from these Libraries.

Comment: Generating debug symbols without complete source code does not seem to be realistic.

Comment: @VTT I had a feeling this was the case but I thought I would check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDB (Symbols) File is linked to the Source Code and it is generate at Linker Time. If you need the PDB from some Lib you need ask for it to the provider otherwise you couldn't generate it.

[image]

Check this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx

The problem with LNK4099 refer that compiler doesn't find the PDB file. You can disable it from the project settings, check these links to see how to handled it:

[How to remove warning LNK4099: PDB 'lib.pdb' was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843883/how-to-remove-warning-lnk4099-pdb-lib-pdb-was-not-found)

[How to deal with 3rd party c++ libraries LNK4099 Warning in VisualStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971324/how-to-deal-with-3rd-party-c-libraries-lnk4099-warning-in-visualstudio)